# How to use absolute layout with two frame?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Absolute layout and I want to add two grid. First frame take 3/1 and second frame will take rest of screen space. So how to do that?
[image]

I am using :

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="Parent">
            <Grid BackgroundColor="Red" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional,WidthProportional" 
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,180"/>
            <Grid x:Name="KeypadGrid" BackgroundColor="Orange">

            </Grid>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using AbsoluteLayout proportional values:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Frame AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,.33" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="Red" >
       ~~~
    </Frame>
    <Frame AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,1,1,.67" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" BackgroundColor="Green" >
       ~~~
    </Frame>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

[image]

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout#absolutelayoutflags

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using Grid. Each height orientation of the device is calculated as 10*. Here I assigned 3* for top and 7* point to be bottom. It will compatible in all devices

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="3*"/> // top
     <RowDefinition Height="7*"/> // bottom
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid/>
```

and add the content you want

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0">
   // view here for top red space
 <Grid/>

 <Grid Grid.Row="1">
  // view here for orange
 <Grid/>
```

Comment: I already do this,but I need to use some absolute position thats whay I as using absolute layout.